# Flask Application - How to link a javascript file to website

Tags: javascript, html, flask, http-status-code-404

I am having some trouble getting started with using javascript files on my website (A Flask application). I start the website by running run.py which looks like this:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

In my html page I have the following code which gives a 404 error:

[image: 404 error]

Error message:

[image: error message]

My file structure looks like this:

[image: file structure]

Any hints to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: where is the page that you are reffering to? i mean the index page..

Comment: i think you'll have to remove `/` before `javascript` in your `<script>` src.

Comment: app/templates/index.html

Comment: okk..could you please show the console error too..

Comment: please try `./javascript`..add a `.` before `/` in your src.

Comment: I've added the error in my OP. Tried adding a . before / but still the same result

Comment: could you please tell the console error when you added `./`

Comment: could you please tell the new console error that you are getting when you tried `.\`.

Comment: also try giving the full path as src.

Comment: The console message was the same for `./`  Using the full path still comes up with a 404 error

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Ah yes, luckily I am currently developing a flask application at the moment.

You are currently missing the **static** folder which by default flask looks into, a folder structure something like this:

```
|FlaskApp
----|FlaskApp
--------|templates
        - html files are here
--------|static
        - css and javascript files are here
```

Two important default folders that Flask will look into templates and **static**.
Once you got that sorted you use this to link up with your javascript files from your html page:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='somejavascriptfile.js')}}"></script>
```

Plus - A good article to read but not super related but it talks about the folder structure of flask is this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: if your javascript code is inside in a blueprint,  you can call it as:  <script src="{{url_for('blueprintName.static', filename='somejavascriptfile.js')}}"></script>  with .notation that way you know exactly where that static file is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Try using `src="app/javascript/jquery.js"`.

Also, I noticed you include jquery.js twice - on line 7 and 28.

Comment: Still getting the same problem

Comment: Do you mean you see 404 for ```http://localhost:5000/app/javascript/jquery.js``` ?

Comment: I also have the exact same problem and moving the javascript file to static works. But I am also wondering if I can have the js file in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

So your `index.html` is at `app/templates/index.html`, and your jQuery is at `app/javascript/jQuery.js` right?

I think your path is wrong. Try this:

```
<script src="../javascript/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I gave that a try but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me eliminate the jquery part of my Flask project

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This was taken straight from Basic Template found in http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/