# javascript file 404 but it's definitely there

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm trying to run a function within a JavaScript file when a button is clicked.

I put the JavaScript file in a scripts folder, and linked to it within my HTML file. It didn't work. I added a link to the physical file on the webpage. I got a 404, despite the file definitely being there.

Here's the structure:

[image]

Here's where I link to the file: 
[image]

Here's the actual button and the created link to the file: 
[image]
Here's the error I'm receiving: 
[image]

Literally anything will help

thanks

Comment: Please don't use links to external resources as part of your question and don't use images of text.

Comment: its in a templates directory.

Comment: When you click on `file.js` in the Network tab, what is the full URL in `Request URL`?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules on the server?

Comment: @DanielA.White It looks like `layout.html` is also in that directory, so the relative URL should work.

Comment: @Barmar the full url is "http://127.0.0.1:5000/templates/scripts/file.js". I'm not sure what you mean by rewrite rules, but if that's something I would have had to setup, I would say no then.

Comment: Check your server log to see what it says when receiving that request.

Comment: All I get is "GET /templates/scripts/file.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Have you tried `../scripts/file.js`?

Comment: what python app framework are you using?

Comment: @sideroxylon unfortunately that didn't work. And I'm using Flask for this project

Comment: The `templates` directory is in your document root?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I think you need to learn how to make a router to a file in Python. For the time being, you can try move script file to the same folder as those html files and change the link to see if it work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011170/flask-application-how-to-link-a-javascript-file-to-website/30011819

Answer (score -1):

The URI is 127.0.0.1:5000/scripts/file.js. The

```
<script src="scripts/file.js"></script>
```

is not using relative location to the folder but rather to the server. You need to do

```
<script src="templates/scripts/file.js"></script>
```

If this templates directory is nested with any other directories from the root, then they too need to be prepended to the src location.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't fix it.

Comment: Try clicking (or double click) on that 404 within the network tab. It may show you where it thinks it is on your physical drive.  That may point you to where the confusion is.

Comment: There's no indication on the network tab of where it physically came from. I think I'm going to pick this up tomorrow with the intention of finding a way to locate where it thinks it is in the physical drive. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This URL is definitely relative to the folder. Relative to the server would be `src="/scripts/file.js"`.

Comment: he said in a comment above that the full URL in the Network tab is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/templates/scripts/file.js`

Comment: I noticed you may be using Firefox. Try opening in Chrome, if available. I, too, was unable to view the physical drive when double clicking on the 404 in Firefox, but double clicking on the error in Chrome showed me the physical drive for my IIS setup.

Comment: Or, if still in firefox. Right click on the 404 line for the Content Menu. Open in new tab.

Comment: Both of these suggestions just reopened the same 127.0.0.1 link.