# How do I import my JS file into my HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, file

I cant seem to get my js file into HTML, anyone know to to transfer to HTML? I'm running this in python and using a flask server.
[This is my javascript code, I'm fairly new to js so just trying it out.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qvQy.png)

[This is my source folder. Pretty much all my files and folders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tCfr.png)

[This is my HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwJzN.png)

Comment: Use "import my JS file into my HTML file" as a keyword to search the result from google.

Answer (score 1):

Change your calling method from

```
<script src="src/testing.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="../src/testing.js"></script>
```

but, I'm not sure in using Flask, maybe this can help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30011819/14963473

Answer (score 0):

Import in html file seems correct. Maybe it's not the problem. Try to add on the beginning of js file:

```
console.log('ok');
```

And check if it will show in console.